# Average of median of a column in a list of dataframes

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am looking for the best way to take the average of median of a column in a list of data frames (same column name).

let's say i have a list of dataframes `list_df`.  I can write the following `for` loop to get the required output.  I am more interested in looking if we can eliminate the `for` loop

```
med_arr = []
list_df = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in list_df:
    med_arr.append(np.median(df['col_name']))
np.mean(med_arr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done as a *list comprehension*:

```
list_df = [ df1, df2, df3 ]
med_arr = [ np.median( df['col_name'] ) for df in list_df ]
np.mean(med_arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sample data

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(col_name=np.random.randint(10, size=10)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(col_name=np.random.randint(10, size=10)))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dict(col_name=np.random.randint(10, size=10)))

list_df = [df1, df2, df3]
```

---

**Option 1**
`pandas`

```
pd.concat([d['col_name'] for d in list_df], axis=1).median().mean()

3.8333333333333335
```

---

**Option 2**
`numpy`

```
np.median([d['col_name'].values for d in list_df], 1).mean()

3.8333333333333335
```